# Does "She leaped clear of the water" mean "She leaped out of the water" or "She leaped far from the water" or "She leaped further from the water"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/leap_1) (item #1 → extra examples):
**(1)** *She leaped **clear of** the water*.

Could you tell me please what (1) can mean?

Does it mean:
**(2)** *She leaped **out of** the water*.
or
**(3)** *She leaped **far from** the water*.
or
**(4)** *She leaped **further from** the water*.

or maybe something else?

update #1:
The aim of my question is to understand what meanings the phrase "clear of" in (1) can have.

update #2 (what led me to the question):
I saw (1).
I didn't understand what "clear of" meant.
I looked up "clear of" in
[ldoceonline.com](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-clear-of-something),
[merriam-webster.com](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clear%20of),
[collinsdictionary.com](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/clear-of),
[thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/clear+of).
From the dictionaries, I inferred that (1) meant (3) or (4).
But the meanings of (3) and (4) seemed strange to me.
I thought maybe (1) meant (2) but I couldn't find any confirmation of this in the dictionaries above.
So I decided to ask what (1) can mean.
Does (1) really mean (3) or (4)?
Or maybe (1) means (2) (in spite of the fact that I couldn't find in the dictionaries that "clear of" can mean "out of")?
Or maybe something else?

Comment: Compare the use of the related verb **clear** in *The sprinter **cleared** the last hurdle in record time.*

Comment: Single preposition ***of*** (as opposed to ***out of***) is slightly unusual for the context IF she was actually ***in*** the water before leaping clear. But if she was actually just ***very close to the water*** (walking along a riverbank or beach shoreline, for example), plain ***of*** would be the natural choice for OP's sense 2 / 3 (those two are essentially the same sense, so far as I'm concerned).

Comment: We need more context. can you give us the surrounding context?

Comment: @gotube My question was edited by another user. In my original post the question was "what **can** the discussed sentence  mean?" implying all meanings corresponding to all contexts which the discussed sentence can have. If you consider the current edited post adds some confusion which my original post didn't have, then ask please about it the user who edited my post.

Comment: @Loviii I've restored your version of the question. Thanks for clearing that up. I'm inferring that the goal of your question is to learn the meaning of "leap clear", or maybe *[ verb of movement + "clear" ]*. Am I close? Please make that clear in your question because giving all the possible meanings of something without any context isn't the kind of question we handle.

Comment: @gotube I've added an update to my post. Could you tell me please it helps to make the question clearer?

Comment: @Loviii Much better. Thanks! I still can't answer though, because it's nearly impossible to give a definite, complete list of every possible meaning of two arbitrary words. Also, it's rarely helpful for learners to learn every possible meaning of something all at once, and it's not a normal use of English to decide to use "clear of", rather than having some function in mind. Are you trying to understand what they mean in a context you saw them in, or are you just curious and thorough?

Comment: @gotube I've added one more update to my post. Could you tell me please it's understandable now what I meant or something still remains unclear?

Comment: @Loviii So you actually just want to understand the meaning of "clear of" in the context of (1) where you found it, and all the other sentences are your guesses. Is that right? If so, as I asked in my first comment above, please give us the full context of that sentence, like who "she" is, what she was doing. It's even better if you can enough of the actual words before and/or after sentence (1) for us to see the context.

Comment: @gotube I don't understand how I can come up with a context for (1), if I don't know what (1) can mean.

Comment: @Loviii You say in your question that you saw sentence (1). I assumed it was in some context. If there was a context, please include it. If there was no context, then the meaning of "clear of" is unclear, and there's no verifiable answer to your question.

Comment: @gotube You wrote: "_You say in your question that you saw sentence (1). I assumed it was in some context._" — Your words seem very strange to me because: The link at the beginning of my post is from a dictionary. Sentence (1) is right after this link. That is, (1) is an example from that dictionary and, therefore, can't have a context. I didn't think this may require an extra clarification...

Comment: @Loviii Oh, I didn't see that link. Now I feel dumb. Sorry for wasting your time. As there's no context to the sentence, it's impossible to say what the original meaning was, and listing every possible meaning of an ambiguous sentence is beyond the scope of this site.

Answer (score 1):

It does mean that she was out of the water (they cleared the water, they were clear of the water), beyond that you'd need to know some context.

For example it might describe a person jumping over a stream.  They jumped right across and didn't go in the water at all.

It might describe a person who has been standing in a pool, but jumps up and completely out of the water.

It might describe a fish that swims up and completely out of the water, but then falls back in again.

It would generally be used when "clear" adds some useful meaning, if three people were all trying to jump over a stream, the first failed and landed in the water, the second landed on the bank, but slipped back into the stream, but the third leapt clear of the water and didn't get her feet wet; for example.

Comment: The similar expression to *jump **clear out of** the water* would mean exiting entirely out of, emphasizing the result of no longer being even a tiny bit within the water.  And *We drove clear through the city without exchanging a word* emphasizes how long they refrained from speaking.

Comment: Is "clear" in "She leaped clear of the water" an adjective or an adverb? Thanks.